# $$ array variable in PHP

Tags: php, reference

I can use $$ variables to refer variable like this

```
$var = 'car';
$car = 'Lamborghini';
echo $$var;
```

Above code will echo **Lamborghini**.

However I am having a code like this:-

```
$var = "['acct_1']['etc']['anotherInfo']['sing']";
$var = 'arr'.$var;
echo $arr['acct_1']['etc']['anotherInfo']['sing'] ;
echo $$var;
```

First echo prints the correct value but $$var doesn't give the correct value.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This obviously doesn't work with arrays

Comment: OK, I will close the question but not able to find the option to do so.

Comment: why, let it be.  check for sometime.

Comment: OK, Probably some work around might be suggested by some one.

Comment: can you please tell why you wrote this:- `$var = 'arr'.$var;`

Comment: Is it necessary that `$var` is in this format? Or could it be `$var = array('arr', 'acct_1', 'etc',..);`?

Comment: Maybe this is solvable with braces?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh - I have to find the key in a multidimensional array and change value of that key at run time. SO I am saving the traversed keys in another array and imploding the keys to change value at run time.

Comment: it's not array it's string man.

Comment: Yes buddy, I wanted to refer array variable like this. Seems its not possible.

Comment: then it's not possible. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can always keep the keys in an array, and then iterate on them to resolve the value correctly:

```
$keys = ['acct_1', 'etc', 'anotherInfo', 'sing'];

$val = $arr;
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $val = $val[$key];
}
```

Now, both `$arr['acct_1']['etc']['anotherInfo']['sing']` and `$val` have the same value.

Try it in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/j9nGVs).

**Edit:**

You already have the `$keys` array in `$indexInfo`. You should be able to use it like so:

```
function replaceValue($arr, $indexInfo, $char)
{
    // $indexInfo is all you need!
    $var = $arr;
    foreach($indexInfo as $key) {
        $var = $var[$key];
    }
    echo $arr['acct_1']['etc']['anotherInfo']['sing'] . "\n";
    echo $var  . "\n";
    die($var);
}
```

Comment: $arr = array(
 'write' => 100,
 'acct_1' => array('blah' => 'foo', 'dance' => 24),
 'acct_1' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 5, 'etc' =>
        array('anotherInfo' => 
          array(
           'info1' => '',
           'sing' => 500000000
          ))),
);
Lets say we have array like this , and now you want to refer sing based on some calculations. So what I am doing is storing the traversed values in an array and then generating the string mentioned in question.

Comment: @JatinDhoot - When you say "storing the traversed values in an array", aren't you forming the exact same array that I called `$keys` in my answer? In which case, you should be able to use that array to implement my answer.

Comment: @JatinDhoot :you said, you are imploding the keys, instead keep those in the array form and apply his logic, Its working fine. Tested with the sample you provided in the above comment

Comment: OK GUys, let me havea look

Comment: @nickb - Mine is multi level nested array, and dimensions are not known in advance

Comment: @JatinDhoot - Maybe you can post more details or explain how you create this variable: `$var = "['acct_1']['etc']['anotherInfo']['sing']";`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f4kyys4d/ Here you can check mate

Comment: @JatinDhoot - I updated my answer, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work unfortunately, however why not do something line this

```
/**
 * Search into a multi dimensional array to find arbitrary data
 * @param array $array The array to search
 * @param string ... Any number of array keys
 * @return mixed
 */
function deepArraySearch(array $array) {
    $keys = func_get_args();
    array_shift($keys); // First element is the array

    // If no more keys to use
    if(!$keys) {
        return $array;
    }

    $nextKey = array_shift($keys);
    $nextData = $array[$nextKey];

    // Nothing left to search
    if(!is_array($nextData )) {
        return $nextData ;
    }

    array_unshift($keys, $nextData);
    return call_user_func_array('deepArraySearch', $keys);
}

$arr = ['one' => ['two' => ['three' => 'data']]];

print_r(deepArraySearch($arr, 'one'));
print_r(deepArraySearch($arr, 'one', 'two'));
print_r(deepArraySearch($arr, 'one', 'two', 'three'));

echo PHP_EOL;
```

In your case I guess it would work like this

```
$arr = ['acct_1' => ['etc' => ['anotherInfo' => ['sing' => 'song']]]];
print_r(deepArraySearch($arr, 'acct_1', 'etc', 'anotherInfo', 'sing')); // song
```

**Final note:**

If you're using PHP 5.6, 7, or HHVM, this function is way nicer:

```
<?php

/**
 * Search into a multi dimensional array to find arbitrary data
 * @param array $array The array to search
 * @param string ... Any number of array keys
 * @return mixed
 */
function deepArraySearch(array $array, ...$keys) {

    // If no more keys to use
    if(!$keys) {
        return $array;
    }

    $nextKey = array_shift($keys);
    $nextData = $array[$nextKey];

    // Nothing left to search
    if(!is_array($nextData )) {
        return $nextData ;
    }

    return deepArraySearch($nextData, ...$keys);
}
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/vmocO